# Substitute for Sum Function for better time performance in LP in Python

Tags: python, performance, linear-programming, pulp

So I was using PULP for modeling a complex LP in Python, for some reasons I decided to test modeling the same problem in Optlang but I noticed that for adding some constraints Optlang was taking too long, that's when I remembered that PULP has the LpSum that returns their custom class LpAfineExpression for Sums, and for Optlang I had to use the default Sum function.

My guess is: The Sum function is what is making the Optlang modeling take too long, so I would like to know if there is a better way to implement the Sum.

This is the code I use to add the constraints in Optlang, where **Per, Emp, Blocks, FT** are lists with the indexes for the variables and coefficients with, respectively, 2154, 8, 1, 1 elements.

```
for (j,k) in product(Per,Emp):
    opt_model.add(optl.Constraint(sum(x_vars[i,j,k,l,Frentes[i]]*TCH[i,j,k,l,Frentes[i]] for (i,l) in product(Blocks,FT) if "F{}{}{}{}{}".format(i,j,k,l,Frentes[i]) in Variables),ub=MOA_max[j,k],lb=MOA_min[j,k],name="TCH{}|{}".format(j,k)))
```

PS: The time difference between PULP and Optlang is like 2 min to 20 min.

Comment: Please add a full example, i.e input data and expected output. It can be a *toy example*, so future answerers could understand your request.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What are the "some reasons" to switch from PuLP to Optlang?